# Pass C# Values To Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

On loading the page I want to pass a value to my javascript function from a server side variable.

I cannot seem to get it to work this is what I have:

Asp.Net

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string blah="ER432";
}
```

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var JavascriptBlah = '<%=blah%>';

    initObject.backg.product_line = JavascriptBlah;

</script>
```

Adding this to the page

```
 public string blah { get; set; }


        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           blah="ER432";
        }
```

I still am getting an error:
CS0103: The name 'blah' does not exist in the current context

Also I would like to try and accomplish this without using hdden fields

Comment: Just to be certain, the `script` tag is in the page that has the .aspx.cs containing `public string blah { get; set; }` declared in it and the page has declared that .aspx.cs file as its code behind right?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe your C# variable must be a class member in order to this. Try declaring it at the class level instead of a local variable of `Page_Load()`. It obviously loses scope once page_load is finished.

```
public partial class Example : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected string blah;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        blah = "ER432";
        //....
```

Comment: I am getting this error:CS0103: The name 'blah' does not exist in the current context

Comment: You must be doing something wrong. Are you doing it similar to my recent edit? I have tested that and it works fine.

Comment: Is my javascript right? It says blah is not in current context

Comment: Ahhhhh! I had the code in a web form and the js in the master page. It worked fine Thanks

Comment: Haha xD glad you figured it out!

Comment: @Shredder - Is there no way to call a variable from the JS in the Master Page?

Comment: @RyanSammut Not unless the variable is in the master class, I don't think so.

Answer (score 3):

In this particular case, `blah` is local to `Page_Load` you'll have to make it a class level member (probably make it a property) for it to be exposed like that.

Answer (score 2):

You can put a hidden input in your html page:

```
<input  type="hidden" runat='server' id="param1" value="" />
```

Then in your code behind set it to what you want to pass to your .js function:

```
param1.value = "myparamvalue"
```

Finally your javascript function can access as below:

```
document.getElementById("param1").value
```

Comment: It's webforms so you'd have to include the `runat="server"` on your input to make it accessible from server code

Comment: You might need to add ClientIDMode=static otherwise the id is adorned with some internal prefixes.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare `blah` at class level.

Comment: @Matthew.. thanks for your help, but make sure when answer is single line or less then it should be a comment, hope you got me!

Comment: @RDC is there a specific rule that says this?  I feel my answer solves the exact problem without inendating the reader with useless information.

Comment: @Matthew.. Nope there is no rule like that, even i agree with you that your answer solve the problem so i gave thanks :) , but as you like to help people same way **we can make better stack-overflow** by managing our Q/A, well..i always Vote up comments those solve the problem or valuable as an answer post.

Answer (score 0):

Your `string blah` needs to be a public property of your `Page` class, not a local variable within `Page_Load`.  You need to learn about scoping.

```
public class MyPage
{
    public string blah { get; set; }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        blah = "ER432";
    }
}
```

Comment: This code is not working for me can you please check my javascript, I am getting an error saying "blah" is not in current context

Answer (score 0):

What I've done in the past is what webforms does as it's functionality--creating a hidden field to store values needed by the client.  If you're using 4.0, you can set the hidden field client id mode to static to help keep things cleaner as well. Basically, add you value to the hidden field and then from javascript you can get the value or modify it too(in case you want to pass it back) since it's just a dom element.

If you really want to use code--like a variable, it needs to be accessible at the class scope.