# Pass data from C# to .aspx and append to <select>

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to retrieve data from database. On page load, I want to pass this data `List<Object>` from C# to .aspx webpage and display them in drop-down list. I use `<select>` for the drop-down list. 

How do I go about doing it? Viewstate?

Comment: Have you even tried to search for an answer ???..

Comment: Look at this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11021066/pass-c-sharp-values-to-javascript

Comment: try to get answer from net you will get

Comment: show some code which you tried...

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple really. Please look at the sample below and pattern it depending on you.

.ASPX Code:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="drpPosition" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
    <asp:ListItem Text="" Value="">- Select Position -</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

.CS Code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection SqlConnect = Connt.GetConnection(TblName); //THIS IS THE CONNECTION STRING

    string qryGetValue = "SELECT COMPANY_CODE, COMPANY_NAME FROM A_COMPANY ORDER BY COMPANY_NAME";
    SqlCommand SqlCmd = new SqlCommand(qryGetValue, SqlConnect);
    SqlConnect.Open();
    SqlDataReader SqlDr = SqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

    drpPosition.DataTextField = "COMPANY_NAME"; //THE VALUE TO DISPLAY IN THE DROPDOWN
    drpPosition.DataValueField = "COMPANY_CODE"; //THE VALUE THAT WILL GET
    drpPosition.DataSource = SqlDr;
    drpPosition.DataBind();
}
```