# Using directive is not recognized although reference exists and target framework is correct

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2017

I want to use a HiddenField on my aspx files and then pass the value from my aspx.cs file to my JS file.

Basically what I want to do is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11021205/9360197) (Dante's comment):

> You can put a hidden input in your html page:
>
> `<input  type="hidden" runat='server' id="param1" value="" />`
>
> Then in your code behind set it to what you want to pass to your .js function:
>
> `param1.value = "myparamvalue"`
>
> Finally your javascript function can be accessed s as below:
>
> `document.getElementById("param1").value`

However I saw that "param1" is not recognized on my aspx.cs file. It says "The name param1 does not exist in current context".

I am sure that:

1. I have used `using System.Web.UI.WebControls;` but it is greyed.
2. I have System.Web on my reference
3. Target Framework is .NET Framework 4.5.2
4. On my aspx header, attribute `CodeBehind` and `Inherits` are exist and correct
5. On my aspx.designer.cs, param1 exists

For information, I have also other Project with .NET Framework 4.5 and I can use Hiddenfield on my aspx.cs.

What am I missing and how do I resolve this?

**EDIT:**

My References:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using System.Xml;
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to do as below

```
<input  type="hidden" runat='server' id="param1" value="" clientidmode="Static" />
```

This hidden field is server control. So we have to set 'clientidmode="Static"' in control, to access from script.

To access from code-behind, just press F12 key on that hidden control in code-behind, then designer.cs page will open and in that page, find the hidden control and change the access modifier to 'public'. Once done, save the page and run. It will work.

Comment: It still won't recognize param1, `using System.Web.UI.WebControls` is also still not recognized

Comment: Can you provide all  references in that page?

Comment: I added the References on EDIT

Comment: Just refer this link, it may be helpful      https://forums.asp.net/t/1585658.aspx?Web+controls+in+code+behind+file+not+recognized